# Is it possible to use Windows Raw Input API without a window (ie from a console application)?

Tags: windows, console, raw-input, message-loop

Is it possible to use Windows Raw Input API without a window (ie from a console application)?

I've tried using RegisterRawInputDevices but my message loops doesn't seem to get *any* events from GetMessage and hence just 'hangs' there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean [`RegisterRawInputDevices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645600.aspx)?

Since the `RAWINPUTDEVICE` structure requires you to specify an `HWND` to receive the `WM_INPUT` messages, no it's not possible to do this without a window.

Console applications can create windows, and the window probably can receive `WM_INPUT` while hidden, but you do need a window.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. RAWINPUTDEVICE seems to work with hwndTarget of NULL as it follows the active window, but it requires a WindowProc to get the WM_INPUT messages.

Comment: @Adam: `hwndTarget` of NULL may be allowed, but it doesn't mean "send to thread" like it does with e.g. `PostMessage`.  If you don't have a window, then you don't have an active window, and no `WM_INPUT` messages will be forthcoming.

Answer (score 7):

That way I did it (not sure it is the most comfortable way...):

I have started a thread (for the task of filling my input buffer).
In this thread I have created a message-only window (its hidden, and can get input datas) with an appropriate window-class.

Then registered the raw input devices.

This thread has its own message handler loop.
In the WindowProc of the window-class I've handled the inputs.

(For buffer, You can use boost:circular_buffer, it ROCKS! :D)

In this solution You did need have a window, but it looks like You don't. :)

I hope this can help.