# Having trouble using winapi to read input from a device

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

I followed the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-raw-input) to try and read some input from a device. I've been trying for a couple hours now to figure out why `GetMessage` doesn't return anything. Originally I was trying to read from a certain device, but seeing as that wasn't working, I wanted to just try reading keyboard or mouse inputs. However, I've had no luck in doing so.

Edit:  Some more info. I'm on Windows 10. I'm running the code in cmder (not sure if that makes any difference) with `python main.py`. There are no error messages and the output is `Successfully registered input device!` before the program just waits to receive a message from `GetMessage`.

Here's the running code:

main.py:

```
from ctypes import windll, sizeof, WinDLL, pointer, c_uint, create_string_buffer, POINTER
from ctypes.wintypes import *
from structures import *
from constants import *  # I put a comment specifying the value for each variable used from here


k32 = WinDLL('kernel32')
GetRawInputDeviceInfo = windll.user32.GetRawInputDeviceInfoA
GetRawInputDeviceInfo.argtypes = HANDLE, UINT, LPVOID, PUINT
RegisterRawInputDevices = windll.user32.RegisterRawInputDevices
RegisterRawInputDevices.argtypes = (RawInputDevice * 7), UINT, UINT
GetMessage = windll.user32.GetMessageA
GetMessage.argtypes = POINTER(Message), HWND, UINT, UINT


def print_error(code=None):
    print(f"Error code {k32.GetLastError() if code is None else code}")


def register_devices(hwnd_target=None):
    # Here I added all usages just to try and get any kind of response from GetMessage
    page = 0x01
    # DW_FLAGS is 0
    devices = (RawInputDevice * 7)(
        RawInputDevice(page, 0x01, DW_FLAGS, hwnd_target),
        RawInputDevice(page, 0x02, DW_FLAGS, hwnd_target),
        RawInputDevice(page, 0x04, DW_FLAGS, hwnd_target),
        RawInputDevice(page, 0x05, DW_FLAGS, hwnd_target),
        RawInputDevice(page, 0x06, DW_FLAGS, hwnd_target),
        RawInputDevice(page, 0x07, DW_FLAGS, hwnd_target),
        RawInputDevice(page, 0x08, DW_FLAGS, hwnd_target),
    )
    if not RegisterRawInputDevices(devices, len(devices), sizeof(devices[0])):
        print_error()
    else:
        print("Successfully registered input device!")


def get_message(h_wnd=None):
    msg = pointer(Message())
    # WM_INPUT is 0
    return_value = GetMessage(msg, h_wnd, WM_INPUT, WM_INPUT)
    if return_value == -1:
        print_error()
    elif return_value == 0:
        print("WM_QUIT message received.")
    else:
        print("Successfully got message!")
        return msg


register_devices()
print(get_message().contents.message)
```

structures.py:

```
from ctypes import Structure
from ctypes.wintypes import *


class RawInputDevice(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("usUsagePage", USHORT),
        ("usUsage", USHORT),
        ("dwFlags", DWORD),
        ("hwndTarget", HWND),
    ]


class Message(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("hwnd", HWND),
        ("message", UINT),
        ("wParam", WPARAM),
        ("lParam", LPARAM),
        ("time", DWORD),
        ("pt", POINT),
        ("lPrivate", DWORD)
    ]
```

I'd appreciate it if anyone helped me figure out what's going wrong, or I'd also be fine if someone can point out an alternative to reading input from an HID device on Windows.

Comment: `print_error()` any error messages?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT There are no error messages.

Comment: What's the output of the code?

Comment: @CristiFati ah right I should've included that. It only outputs `Successfully registered input device!` and then the program continues running waiting for a response from GetMessage, which it never gets.

Comment: `GetMessage` nothing output too ?!

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT Yep, `GetMessage` does not output anything.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/using-raw-input

Comment: @CristiFati I've already read that page and it didn't help.

Comment: That's because you didn't follow what's in there. You should create a window, and in that window's *WndProc*, handle *WM\_INPUT*.

Comment: @CristiFati Ok then I'll try creating a window, thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: are you allowed / open to using some 3rd-party *Python* modules?

Comment: @CristiFati I would use some 3rd-party modules as a last resort since I'm mostly doing this for educational purposes.

Comment: *CTypes* is handy (personally I like it), but when there are lots of *API*s (and structures, constants, ...) involved, I prefer *PyWin32* as it requires much less boilerplate code. Also as a hint, you can use *PeekMessage* instead of *GetMessage*, and your app would not block, but it still won't do what you're expecting.

Comment: @CristiFati Ok I'll consider using PyWin32 if I don't get anywhere soon. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to start with the (main) resources:

- [[MS.Learn]: Using Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/using-raw-input)
- [[SO]: getrawinputdata within a simple main()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49572093/4788546)
- [[SO]: Is it possible to use Windows Raw Input API without a window (ie from a console application)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6800982/4788546)
- [[CodeProject]: Minimal Key Logger Using RAWINPUT](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/297312/Minimal-Key-Logger-using-RAWINPUT)
- [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)
- [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32)
- [[ME.TimGolden]: Python for Win32 Extensions Help](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html)

I prepared an example.

*ctypes_wrappers.py*:

```py
import ctypes as cts
import ctypes.wintypes as wts


HCURSOR = cts.c_void_p
LRESULT = cts.c_ssize_t

wndproc_args = (wts.HWND, wts.UINT, wts.WPARAM, wts.LPARAM)

WNDPROC = cts.CFUNCTYPE(LRESULT, *wndproc_args)

kernel32 = cts.WinDLL("Kernel32")
user32 = cts.WinDLL("User32")


def structure_to_string_method(self):
    ret = [f"{self.__class__.__name__} (size: {cts.sizeof(self.__class__)}) instance at 0x{id(self):016X}:"]
    for fn, _ in self._fields_:
        ret.append(f"  {fn}: {getattr(self, fn)}")
    return "\n".join(ret) + "\n"

union_to_string_method = structure_to_string_method


class Struct(cts.Structure):
    to_string = structure_to_string_method


class Uni(cts.Union):
    to_string = union_to_string_method


class WNDCLASSEXW(Struct):
    _fields_ = (
        ("cbSize", wts.UINT),
        ("style", wts.UINT),
        #("lpfnWndProc", cts.c_void_p),
        ("lpfnWndProc", WNDPROC),
        ("cbClsExtra", cts.c_int),
        ("cbWndExtra", cts.c_int),
        ("hInstance", wts.HINSTANCE),
        ("hIcon", wts.HICON),
        ("hCursor", HCURSOR),
        ("hbrBackground", wts.HBRUSH),
        ("lpszMenuName", wts.LPCWSTR),
        ("lpszClassName", wts.LPCWSTR),
        ("hIconSm", wts.HICON),
    )

WNDCLASSEX = WNDCLASSEXW


class RawInputDevice(Struct):
    _fields_ = (
        ("usUsagePage", wts.USHORT),
        ("usUsage", wts.USHORT),
        ("dwFlags", wts.DWORD),
        ("hwndTarget", wts.HWND),
    )

PRawInputDevice = cts.POINTER(RawInputDevice)


class RAWINPUTHEADER(Struct):
    _fields_ = (
        ("dwType", wts.DWORD),
        ("dwSize", wts.DWORD),
        ("hDevice", wts.HANDLE),
        ("wParam", wts.WPARAM),
    )


class RAWMOUSE(Struct):
    _fields_ = (
        ("usFlags", wts.USHORT),
        ("ulButtons", wts.ULONG),  # unnamed union: 2 USHORTS: flags, data
        ("ulRawButtons", wts.ULONG),
        ("lLastX", wts.LONG),
        ("lLastY", wts.LONG),
        ("ulExtraInformation", wts.ULONG),
    )


class RAWKEYBOARD(Struct):
    _fields_ = (
        ("MakeCode", wts.USHORT),
        ("Flags", wts.USHORT),
        ("Reserved", wts.USHORT),
        ("VKey", wts.USHORT),
        ("Message", wts.UINT),
        ("ExtraInformation", wts.ULONG),
    )


class RAWHID(Struct):
    _fields_ = (
        ("dwSizeHid", wts.DWORD),
        ("dwCount", wts.DWORD),
        ("bRawData", wts.BYTE * 1),  # @TODO - cfati: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-rawhid, but not very usable via CTypes
    )


class RAWINPUT_U0(Uni):
    _fields_ = (
        ("mouse", RAWMOUSE),
        ("keyboard", RAWKEYBOARD),
        ("hid", RAWHID),
    )


class RAWINPUT(Struct):
    _fields_ = (
        ("header", RAWINPUTHEADER),
        ("data", RAWINPUT_U0),
    )

PRAWINPUT = cts.POINTER(RAWINPUT)


GetLastError = kernel32.GetLastError
GetLastError.argtypes = ()
GetLastError.restype = wts.DWORD

GetModuleHandle = kernel32.GetModuleHandleW
GetModuleHandle.argtypes = (wts.LPWSTR,)
GetModuleHandle.restype = wts.HMODULE


DefWindowProc = user32.DefWindowProcW
DefWindowProc.argtypes = wndproc_args
DefWindowProc.restype = LRESULT

RegisterClassEx = user32.RegisterClassExW
RegisterClassEx.argtypes = (cts.POINTER(WNDCLASSEX),)
RegisterClassEx.restype = wts.ATOM

CreateWindowEx = user32.CreateWindowExW
CreateWindowEx.argtypes = (wts.DWORD, wts.LPCWSTR, wts.LPCWSTR, wts.DWORD, cts.c_int, cts.c_int, cts.c_int, cts.c_int, wts.HWND, wts.HMENU, wts.HINSTANCE, wts.LPVOID)
CreateWindowEx.restype = wts.HWND

RegisterRawInputDevices = user32.RegisterRawInputDevices
RegisterRawInputDevices.argtypes = (PRawInputDevice, wts.UINT, wts.UINT)
RegisterRawInputDevices.restype = wts.BOOL

GetRawInputData = user32.GetRawInputData
GetRawInputData.argtypes = (PRAWINPUT, wts.UINT, wts.LPVOID, wts.PUINT, wts.UINT)
GetRawInputData.restype = wts.UINT

GetMessage = user32.GetMessageW
GetMessage.argtypes = (wts.LPMSG, wts.HWND, wts.UINT, wts.UINT)
GetMessage.restype = wts.BOOL

PeekMessage = user32.PeekMessageW
PeekMessage.argtypes = (wts.LPMSG, wts.HWND, wts.UINT, wts.UINT, wts.UINT)
PeekMessage.restype = wts.BOOL

TranslateMessage = user32.TranslateMessage
TranslateMessage.argtypes = (wts.LPMSG,)
TranslateMessage.restype = wts.BOOL

DispatchMessage = user32.DispatchMessageW
DispatchMessage.argtypes = (wts.LPMSG,)
DispatchMessage.restype = LRESULT

PostQuitMessage = user32.PostQuitMessage
PostQuitMessage.argtypes = (cts.c_int,)
PostQuitMessage.restype = None
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as cts
import ctypes.wintypes as wts
import sys
import time

import ctypes_wrappers as cws


HWND_MESSAGE = -3

WM_QUIT = 0x0012
WM_INPUT = 0x00FF
WM_KEYUP = 0x0101
WM_CHAR = 0x0102

HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC = 0x01

RIDEV_NOLEGACY = 0x00000030
RIDEV_INPUTSINK = 0x00000100
RIDEV_CAPTUREMOUSE = 0x00000200

RID_HEADER = 0x10000005
RID_INPUT = 0x10000003

RIM_TYPEMOUSE = 0
RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD = 1
RIM_TYPEHID = 2

PM_NOREMOVE = 0x0000


def wnd_proc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
    print(f"Handle message - hwnd: 0x{hwnd:016X} msg: 0x{msg:08X} wp: 0x{wparam:016X} lp: 0x{lparam:016X}")
    if msg == WM_INPUT:
        size = wts.UINT(0)
        res = cws.GetRawInputData(cts.cast(lparam, cws.PRAWINPUT), RID_INPUT, None, cts.byref(size), cts.sizeof(cws.RAWINPUTHEADER))
        if res == wts.UINT(-1) or size == 0:
            print_error(text="GetRawInputData 0")
            return 0
        buf = cts.create_string_buffer(size.value)
        res = cws.GetRawInputData(cts.cast(lparam, cws.PRAWINPUT), RID_INPUT, buf, cts.byref(size), cts.sizeof(cws.RAWINPUTHEADER))
        if res != size.value:
            print_error(text="GetRawInputData 1")
            return 0
        #print("kkt: ", cts.cast(lparam, cws.PRAWINPUT).contents.to_string())
        ri = cts.cast(buf, cws.PRAWINPUT).contents
        #print(ri.to_string())
        head = ri.header
        print(head.to_string())
        #print(ri.data.mouse.to_string())
        #print(ri.data.keyboard.to_string())
        #print(ri.data.hid.to_string())
        if head.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE:
            data = ri.data.mouse
        elif head.dwType == RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD:
            data = ri.data.keyboard
            if data.VKey == 0x1B:
                cws.PostQuitMessage(0)
        elif head.dwType == RIM_TYPEHID:
            data = ri.data.hid
        else:
            print("Wrong raw input type!!!")
            return 0
        print(data.to_string())
    return cws.DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam)


def print_error(code=None, text=None):
    text = text + " - e" if text else "E"
    code = cws.GetLastError() if code is None else code
    print(f"{text}rror code: {code}")


def register_devices(hwnd=None):
    flags = RIDEV_INPUTSINK  # @TODO - cfati: If setting to 0, GetMessage hangs
    generic_usage_ids = (0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08)
    devices = (cws.RawInputDevice * len(generic_usage_ids))(
        *(cws.RawInputDevice(HID_USAGE_PAGE_GENERIC, uid, flags, hwnd) for uid in generic_usage_ids)
    )
    #for d in devices: print(d.usUsagePage, d.usUsage, d.dwFlags, d.hwndTarget)
    if cws.RegisterRawInputDevices(devices, len(generic_usage_ids), cts.sizeof(cws.RawInputDevice)):
        print("Successfully registered input device(s)!")
        return True
    else:
        print_error(text="RegisterRawInputDevices")
        return False


def main(*argv):
    wnd_cls = "SO049572093_RawInputWndClass"
    wcx = cws.WNDCLASSEX()
    wcx.cbSize = cts.sizeof(cws.WNDCLASSEX)
    #wcx.lpfnWndProc = cts.cast(cws.DefWindowProc, cts.c_void_p)
    wcx.lpfnWndProc = cws.WNDPROC(wnd_proc)
    wcx.hInstance = cws.GetModuleHandle(None)
    wcx.lpszClassName = wnd_cls
    #print(dir(wcx))
    res = cws.RegisterClassEx(cts.byref(wcx))
    if not res:
        print_error(text="RegisterClass")
        return 0
    hwnd = cws.CreateWindowEx(0, wnd_cls, None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, None, wcx.hInstance, None)
    if not hwnd:
        print_error(text="CreateWindowEx")
        return 0
    #print("hwnd:", hwnd)
    if not register_devices(hwnd):
        return 0
    msg = wts.MSG()
    pmsg = cts.byref(msg)
    print("Start loop (press <ESC> to exit)...")
    while res := cws.GetMessage(pmsg, None, 0, 0):
        if res < 0:
            print_error(text="GetMessage")
            break
        cws.TranslateMessage(pmsg)
        cws.DispatchMessage(pmsg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                    64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q071994439]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Handle message - hwnd: 0x00000000002F0606 msg: 0x00000024 wp: 0x0000000000000000 lp: 0x000000F5E0BEDDE0
> Handle message - hwnd: 0x00000000002F0606 msg: 0x00000081 wp: 0x0000000000000000 lp: 0x000000F5E0BEDD70
> Handle message - hwnd: 0x00000000002F0606 msg: 0x00000083 wp: 0x0000000000000000 lp: 0x000000F5E0BEDE00
> Handle message - hwnd: 0x00000000002F0606 msg: 0x00000001 wp: 0x0000000000000000 lp: 0x000000F5E0BEDD70
> Successfully registered input device(s)!
> Start loop (press <ESC> to exit)...
> Handle message - hwnd: 0x00000000002F0606 msg: 0x0000031F wp: 0x0000000000000001 lp: 0x0000000000000000
> Handle message - hwnd: 0x00000000002F0606 msg: 0x000000FF wp: 0x0000000000000001 lp: 0x-00000003849FCDF
> RAWINPUTHEADER (size: 24) instance at 0x00000296313BBBC0:
>   dwType: 1
>   dwSize: 40
>   hDevice: 843780541
>   wParam: 1
>
> RAWKEYBOARD (size: 16) instance at 0x00000296313BBCC0:
>   MakeCode: 30
>   Flags: 0
>   Reserved: 0
>   VKey: 65
>   Message: 256
>   ExtraInformation: 0
>
> Handle message - hwnd: 0x00000000002F0606 msg: 0x000000FF wp: 0x0000000000000001 lp: 0x0000000031AE1619
> RAWINPUTHEADER (size: 24) instance at 0x00000296313BBBC0:
>   dwType: 1
>   dwSize: 40
>   hDevice: 843780541
>   wParam: 1
>
> RAWKEYBOARD (size: 16) instance at 0x00000296313BBD40:
>   MakeCode: 30
>   Flags: 1
>   Reserved: 0
>   VKey: 65
>   Message: 257
>   ExtraInformation: 0
>
> Handle message - hwnd: 0x00000000002F0606 msg: 0x000000FF wp: 0x0000000000000001 lp: 0x000000007C851501
> RAWINPUTHEADER (size: 24) instance at 0x00000296313BBBC0:
>   dwType: 0
>   dwSize: 48
>   hDevice: 4461491
>   wParam: 1
>
> RAWMOUSE (size: 24) instance at 0x00000296313BBDC0:
>   usFlags: 0
>   ulButtons: 1
>   ulRawButtons: 0
>   lLastX: 0
>   lLastY: 0
>   ulExtraInformation: 0
>
> Handle message - hwnd: 0x00000000002F0606 msg: 0x000000FF wp: 0x0000000000000001 lp: 0x0000000031B41619
> RAWINPUTHEADER (size: 24) instance at 0x00000296313BBBC0:
>   dwType: 0
>   dwSize: 48
>   hDevice: 4461491
>   wParam: 1
>
> RAWMOUSE (size: 24) instance at 0x00000296313BBE40:
>   usFlags: 0
>   ulButtons: 2
>   ulRawButtons: 0
>   lLastX: 0
>   lLastY: 0
>   ulExtraInformation: 0
>
> Handle message - hwnd: 0x00000000002F0606 msg: 0x000000FF wp: 0x0000000000000001 lp: 0x0000000052D10665
> RAWINPUTHEADER (size: 24) instance at 0x00000296313BBBC0:
>   dwType: 1
>   dwSize: 40
>   hDevice: 843780541
>   wParam: 1
>
> RAWKEYBOARD (size: 16) instance at 0x00000296313BBEC0:
>   MakeCode: 1
>   Flags: 0
>   Reserved: 0
>   VKey: 27
>   Message: 256
>   ExtraInformation: 0
>
>
> Done.
> ```

**Notes**:

- The (above) output was generated by the following actions: <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>LClick</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd>
- I gave up on *PyWin32*, as it doesn't wrap the functions that we need (none of the *Raw Input* family), but it might be used (at least) for the constants from *Win32Con* (to avoid defining them)
- I think things can be simplified, by moving functionality from *wnd_proc* to the *while* loop from *main* (and thus all the window class stuff (constants, structures, functions) could be dropped), but I started this way and I don't feel like changing it
- A major breakthrough was *RIDEV_INPUTSINK* (since then, *GetMessage* stopped hanging)
- *RAWHID* structure (***@TODO***) is wrapped "by the book", but it won't work *OOTB* (you mentioned working with other type of devices). That (1 sized) array at the end is just a way of stating that some additional data (*dwSizeHid* sized) will follow, which obviously won't fit in one byte. A "trick" is required there: the structure must be dynamically defined, based on the size of the data (example: [[SO]: Setting _fields_ dynamically in ctypes.Structure (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30801487/4788546)) - I remember that I wrote a newer answer on that topic, but I can't find or remember it), and all that behavior propagated (recursively) in all structures (unions) that encapsulate it

Answer (score -2):

GetMessage is for use in a message pump, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage. I do not know what you should use but GetMessage definitely is not meant for such use.

Comment: The documentation says to use GetMessage to receive a WM_INPUT event which I can then use to execute GetRawInputData. I'm first trying to get a WM_INPUT event from GetMessage, and then I will build the rest of the code for making it all work properly.

Comment: OK, but then you should it in a message pump as in the example on MS (while... etc).